# Unable to overlay component in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have the following modal component:

```
export default function LoginModal(props) {
    const { showLogin, hideLogin } = props
    if (!showLogin) return null
    return (
        <div class='overlay'>
            <div class='modal'>
                <article class='mw5 center bg-white br3 pa3 pa4-ns mv3 ba b--black-10'>
                    <div class='tc'>
                        <h1 class='f4'>Firstname Lastname</h1>
                        <hr class='mw3 bb bw1 b--black-10' />
                    </div>
                    <p class='lh-copy measure center f6 black-70'>
                        test test test test
                    </p>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

which I am attempting to conditionally render using a state property stored in my redux store. However, when I place it as follows:

```
<article class='pv6 center ph3 ph5-ns tc br2 bg-washed-green dark-green mb5'>
    PAGE CONTENT HERE           
</article>
<LoginModal />
```

It appears below the rest of the screen content rather than above everything else as I had hoped. I am using the following css to try to get this effect, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
.overlay {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
    padding: 50;
    z-index: 300;
}

.modal {
    background-color: '#fff';
    border-radius: 5;
    max-width: 500;
    min-height: 300;
    margin: '0 auto';
    padding: 30;
}
```

I need the modal to appear as a login card in the center of the screen with the background dimmed, as is common on many websites. I would also rather not use a UI component library to achieve. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a `position: fixed` in your `.overlay` styles.

Also, you might want to consider using [Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to render the modal outside the DOM hierarchy of your App, that is, outside the `<div id="app"></div>` or `<div id="root"></div>` we commonly use.

To do that, your `index.html` or equivalent file would have something like this:

```
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="modal"></div>
```

And then you need to update your `LoginModal` like this:

```
export default function LoginModal(props) {

  const { showLogin, hideLogin } = props;

  if (!showLogin) return null;

  return ReactDOM.createPortal((
    <div class='overlay'>
      <div class='modal'>
        <article class='mw5 center bg-white br3 pa3 pa4-ns mv3 ba b--black-10'>
          <div class='tc'>
            <h1 class='f4'>Firstname Lastname</h1>

            <hr class='mw3 bb bw1 b--black-10' />
          </div>

          <p class='lh-copy measure center f6 black-70'>
            test test test test
          </p>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div> 
  ), document.getElementById('modal'));

}
```

Note that if you try to reuse the code in this example to create a generic `Modal` component, you would only be able to show one at a time, as they would be rendering inside the same `#modal` element.

In the [Portals documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) you can see an example that creates a new element dynamically so that you can have multiple modals at the same time.

Comment: So your suggestion with regards to the CSS fix worked perfectly, however, I tried to render my modal using Portals as you described but for some reason, it does not appear on screen. Do you have any ideas as to why this is the case?

Comment: Does the element you are using as root actually exist on the page? In this example, it would be `document.getElementById('modal')`, so you need an element with `id="modal"` for this to work. Did you get any error? That being said, the main issue in your code was the missing `position: fixed`, so you might not need to use Portals if your application is not too complex.